# Subtracting 1 from a Console.ReadKey().KeyChar

Tags: c#

As a personal project to increase my coding skills I'm creating a small cmd-line text game. This program takes in user input via the following line:
char Answer = char.ToUpper(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar)

For the most part in this program, it works quite well, user hits a button and it automatically grabs what the user typed (this answer is mainly used in listed choice options), however, I've got a bug where a user can type a number not displayed in a list. Below is an example of how this is occurring.

```
PrintMessage.print(ViewEnter(character, input), 4);

for (int i = 0; i < x.buildings[character.CurBuild].Rooms.Length; i++)
{
    PrintMessage.print("\t" + (i + 1) + " - Room " + (i + 1));
}

try
{
    PrintMessage.printSame("Choice: ", 4);
    answer = Console.ReadKey(true);
    Console.Clear();

    if (int.TryParse(answer.KeyChar.ToString(), out num))
    {
        character.CurRoom = num - 1;
        PrintMessage.print("You enter the " + 
            x.buildings[character.CurBuild].rooms[character.CurRoom].areaDescription);
    }
}
catch
{
    PrintMessage.printError("Please enter a valid selection.");
}
```

The for loop displays a list of valid choices for the user to type in. i+1 is for user-friendly number values for the list (so instead of the first choice being a 0, it displays as a 1). However, I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to subtract a numerical value from the user input for list displays like shown above. My gut-response is to just recode my method of user input, which would cancel this bug and any others similar to it (that I currently have).

This bug affects two areas, when a player enters a building or when the player enters a room. Both use the same style of code, just a different variable based on where their current location it.

Is there a semi-simple or elegant way to subtract 1 from a Console.ReadKey()? If push comes to shove I don't mind recoding my user inputs, I'm just hoping there might be a way out there.

Comment: The subtraction would have to take place after parsing the input string to an `int`. It looks like you're already doing what needs to happen on the line `character.CurRoom = num - 1;`?

Comment: *"I've got a bug where a user can type a number not displayed in a list"* is not the same as *"How to subtract 1 from Console.ReadKey()"*. It sounds like your question is about how to restrict the user input to valid numbers, correct?

Comment: @itsme86: That line is used to store the position of the player. character.CurRoom is a variable I'm using in the character class and is called/edited when the player transitions to a new room/building/area (3 variables like that, CurRoom/CurBuilding/CurArea)

Comment: @RufusL:
Yes and no, I'm using the Console.ReadKey().KeyChar as it allows me to do both numerical and character inputs for simple inputs. For complex (like a "move" or "look") command I'm doing actual string.

Comment: @RufusL: In this specific question, I'm asking is there a method to subtract an int value of 1 from whatever the user input. So before the if(int.TryParse) but after the answer = Console.ReadKey(true) is my best guess as to where this would take place.

Comment: Technically you can, but it won't give you the answer you want (you'll get the ascii value of the character, not the number it represents). You need to convert it to an `int` first as you're doing.

Comment: I guess an alternative method of explaining it would be the for-loop is displaying a modified value, so first position is displayed as 1 rather than 0. The user hits the 1 key as that may be their choice, however from what it looks like is going on the program passes 1 as their choice, which according to the program would actually be the second listed option (which the for loop displays as option 2).

Comment: The `try / catch` isn't helping you here.  The int parse is safe (will return false rather than throw - which is good, bad input isn't exceptional), so short of your `Console` or `PrintMessage` functions throwing, there isn't anything to catch.  Instead you should use an `if` statement like @RufusL coded that reports if the character is invalid and then returns back to the `ReadKey` stage

Comment: @Rudu: Thank you for that information. This project of mine kind of took off on its own so I'm confident when I say: I've probably got loads of inefficiencies or just badly-written code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict the user input to only valid numbers, then you can just check this in your `if` condition by checking that the number is greater than zero and less than or equal to the length of the array (this is the range of numbers you're presenting them as options). Then you can subtract `1` from it to use as an index:

```
if (int.TryParse(answer.KeyChar.ToString(), out num) && 
    num > 0 && num <= x.buildings[character.CurBuild].Rooms.Length)
{
    character.CurRoom = num - 1;
    PrintMessage.print("You enter the " + 
        x.buildings[character.CurBuild].rooms[character.CurRoom].areaDescription);
}
```

---

As a side note, the `try\catch` isn't catching anything, because `int.TryParse` doesn't throw an exception. Instead what we can do is put the condition in a `do\while` loop, which keeps asking for input until a valid response is returned:

```
// This do/while loop will continue until the user enters a valid number
do
{
    PrintMessage.print(ViewEnter(character, input), 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < x.buildings[character.CurBuild].Rooms.Length; i++)
    {
        PrintMessage.print("\t" + (i + 1) + " - Room " + (i + 1));
    }

    PrintMessage.printSame("Choice: ", 4);
    answer = Console.ReadKey(true);
    Console.Clear();
} while (!int.TryParse(answer.KeyChar.ToString(), out num) || 
         num < 1 || num > x.buildings[character.CurBuild].Rooms.Length);

// When we exit the loop, we know that `num` is valid. Now we subtract `1` and continue
character.CurRoom = num - 1;
PrintMessage.print("You enter the " + 
    x.buildings[character.CurBuild].rooms[character.CurRoom].areaDescription);
```

Comment: Just attempted this, it did not appear to work. However, upon further testing, it looks like I've got an entirely different issue: my movement code does not actually move the player, or rather the new location for the player to be in isn't getting stored properly.

Comment: Ah, ok. I updated the answer with an alternate way to loop until the user enters a valid number, but it sounds like you have another problem to solve now

Comment: I saw that and I'm working on adding in your tweaks now. Will edit this message once I've done some testing.

Comment: So I tried your block of code above (do-while) and it threw an Out of Range exception on the for loop that displays the list of buildings in the player's current area.

Comment: I just copied your code - it means that `character.CurBuild` is invalid, but that's not in my control.

Answer (score 0):

The `try / catch` isn't helping you here (see my comment above).  While Rufus has given you an answer, you also need to modify your reading loop so you keep asking for input while it's invalid.. I'd separate that into a method like so:

```
private int ReadRoom(int maxRoom,int minRoom=1) {
    for(var i=minRoom;i<=maxRoom;i++) {
        PrintMessage.print("\t" + i + " - Room " + i);
    }
    while (true) {
        PrintMessage.printSame("Choice: ", 4);
        answer = Console.ReadKey(true);
        Console.Clear();
        if (!int.TryParse(answer.KeyChar.ToString(),out num)) {
            //You may want to combine this with the next block (or 
            //change the message to list all valid inputs)
            PrintMessage.printError("Expecting a number");
        } else if (num<minRoom || num>maxRoom) {
            PrintMessage.printError("Please choose a valid room ("+minRoom+"-"+maxRoom+")");
        } else {
            //The room is in the right range, so return it to the calling function
            return num-1;
        }
    }
}

public void YourFunc() {
    //...
    PrintMessage.print(ViewEnter(character, input), 4);
    character.CurRoom = ReadRoom(1,x.buildings[character.CurBuild].Rooms.Length);
    PrintMessage.print("You enter the " + 
        x.buildings[character.CurBuild].rooms[character.CurRoom].areaDescription);
    //...
}
```

Where `YourFunc` is just an example name for wherever your example code is.  Note `ReadRoom` will eternally ask for input until a valid number between `minRoom` and `maxRoom` is input (you probably also want to read control characters here.. perhaps `esc` exits the program so it should also be allowed here?

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank all of you for your assistance. After trying what each of you has posted I came to the realization that the current version of it got wildly out of my initial scope (self-feature creeping) for this project, I tried doing too many things too quickly without making sure that the foundations of it were functioning properly. To that effect (and why I"m posting an answer to my own question), I've moved my current version to a new branch (labeled Defunct) and will be starting over while trying to make a more solid foundation.

This project was, as I stated above in the question, purely personal for me to get better at code and learn how to do new things (one of which was a procedural area generator) and I started this back in 2015 (off and on, moved to other things for a few years).

Thank you again for your help everyone.